# Update Table 1 Column with Count of second Table Then An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql-server

```
UPDATE
  Table
SET
  Table.col1 = Count(other_table.id)
FROM
  Table
INNER JOIN
  other_table
ON
  Table.id = other_table.id
```

I want to update Table 1 Column with the count of table 2 but I found this error when I update "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement."

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, update the table based on count of corresponding entries in other table?

Comment: yes. Actually I want to update the count on corresponding entries

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
  Table
SET
  Table.col1 = (Select Count(other_table.id)
                 FROM
                   other_table
                 Where
                   Table.id = other_table.id)
```

Working example 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/574fc/1

Comment: Please consider elaborating on your answer.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with your code my friend. I'm merely suggesting you explain why this will work so the OP understands. Also this is simply a suggestion since you answer popped up in the review queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using common table expression:

```
;WITH data AS(
    SELECT t.id, COUNT(ot.id) cnt
    FROM table t
    INNER JOIN other_table ot
        ON t.id = ot.id
)
UPDATE Table 
SET t.col1 = d.cnt 
FROM table t 
INNER JOIN data d 
    ON t.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Table.col1 = OT.C
FROM
    Table T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS C
    FROM other_table
    GROUP BY id
) OT
ON
    T.id = OT.id
```